# Mesh sticks to rigify controls when moving on a locked axis

Tags: animation, rigging, rigify

[image]When I'm using rigify, moving certain IK layers such as the Leg IK, the mesh "sticks to the control. See attached picture. You can't really tell, but I have the LegIK locked to
I've watched some tutorials and their meshes don't stay attached after moving a certain distance. And it doesn't have such extreme deformation.

Answer (score 0):

This is the default behaviour of IK limbs in rigify.
There are different things that you can do to change it. The easiest one is to turn IK stretch off
[image]